# Idempotent queries of time series data in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, splunk

I often use Camel's idempotent pattern to prevent duplicate processing of discrete messages.  **What's the best practice to do this when the data stream in question is a large volume of messages each with a timestamp?**

Consider this route configuration (pseudocode):

> timer -> idempotent( search_splunk_as_batch -> split -> sql(insert))

We want to periodically query from splunk and write to sql.  We don't want to miss any messages and we don't want any duplicate messages.

Instead of persisting an idempotent marker for each message, I'd like to note the cutoff time for each batch and begin the next query at the cutoff time.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will probably work as long as you can rely on some assumptions:

- Your indexers never load data that appears in the past (according to the `_time` field)
- Your camel route is never running in more than one process at a time that is sending to the same database table.

If you can make sure these are met, then you can just store the maximum timestamp that you receive from the search and use that with the "`earliest`" parameter of the splunk search command.  Storing and retrieving the max timestamp could be done with something like a file, a separate database table, or using a column in your target table.

Comment: Thanks, good points.  So are you aware of any existing pattern (i.e. Idempotent Consumer) available for doing this sort of thing or should we roll our own?